# Send array to my database from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, database

i'm trying to add tags of user interest using MultiAutoCompleteTextView in android studio, but here i get the result in array, how can i send array to MySql using i want help in making php file.

here is my android code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] str={"Andoid","Jelly Bean","Froyo",
            "Ginger Bread","Eclipse Indigo","Eclipse Juno"};

    MultiAutoCompleteTextView mt=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    mt.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);

    mt.setThreshold(1);
    mt.setAdapter(adp);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the string by adding , to end of all of them and the new string to server using httpurlconnection or store it in local database